# Correcting crashing/grub issues with partially failed install

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 16.04, mdadm

I had issues completing grub installation on an mdadm system with 16.04, and managed to hack it to boot. However now the system intermittently crashes and continually tries and fails to install grub-efi packages. **I do not have the time to spend another afternoon reinstalling**.

The drive setup on the system is as follows:

```
NAME      SIZE TYPE  FSTYPE            PARTTYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       1.8T disk                             
├─sda1      1G part  ext4              0x83     /boot
├─sda2    100G part  linux_raid_member 0x83     
│ └─md0 199.9G raid0 ext4                       /
├─sda3    1.7T part  linux_raid_member 0x83     
│ └─md2   1.7T raid1 ext4                       /home
└─sda4     32G part  linux_raid_member 0x83     
  └─md1    64G raid0 swap                       [SWAP]
sdb       1.8T disk                             
├─sdb1      1G part  ext4              0x83     
├─sdb2    100G part  linux_raid_member 0x83     
│ └─md0 199.9G raid0 ext4                       /
├─sdb3    1.7T part  linux_raid_member 0x83     
│ └─md2   1.7T raid1 ext4                       /home
└─sdb4     32G part  linux_raid_member 0x83     
  └─md1    64G raid0 swap                       [SWAP]
```

What I tried:

1. Installation went fine, until grub installation, which failed
2. Tried boot-repair, and grub-install, neither of which worked (I mounted the target drives and boot partition before doing so)

   - grub-install fails: "cannot find EFI directory"
3. I do not need EFI boot, so used grub-install --target=i386-pc

   - grub-install fails: "cannot find /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc"
4. I made an assumtion, I thought that there was likely a version of these files on the linux livecd, so copied them from `[livecd]/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc` to `[target]/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc`, which actually allowed grub to install

What I'm dealing with now

- The system will boot, but takes longer than I would expect for a fresh install
- Whenever apt-get is run, packages `grub-efi-amd64-signed`, and `shim-signed` attempt to, and fail to install with the same efi error from above
- The system occasionally hard locks, looking at the syslogs, there are mentions of the **Live CD installer** starting and otherwise not many errors

Help me, you're my only hope.